# Docs for DOM Event composedPath() method

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm looking at the [specification for the Event interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-event), and it references the following method: `sequence<EventTarget> composedPath();`. I'm also looking at the [MDN Docs for Event methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#Methods), and there's no method of `composedPath` that I can find. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: It is mentioned here but leads to [404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking in the right places, but it's a relatively recent addition (so called ShadowDOM v1; there used to be `Event.path` and `Event.deepPath` in previous iterations), so MDN hasn't been updated with it yet.

The method [was implemented in Firefox 59 and the bug has a `dev-doc-needed` keyword](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1412775) indicating that the documentation is yet to be updated for this. Feel free to [help out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Getting_started)!